# Limpiar memoria de script pyshark

Tags: python, manejo-de-memoria

Hola estoy usando pyshark para escuchar datos en ciertas ip's y mandar los datos procesados a una base de datos, el script se ejecuta como servicio de windows porque se debe ejecutar 24/7, el codigo muy resumido queda de la siguiente manera

```
import pyshark
import mysql.connector

def capture_tcp(timeout=30):
    capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(bpf_filter='tcp')
    capture.sniff(timeout=timeout)
    return capture 

while True:
    dbConnector()
    for package in capture_tcp():
        #procesos varios
```

el problema radica en que no limpia la memoria y el proceso llega a pesar mucho, como dato extra he observado que el `for` no termina como tal, por ejemplo si `capture_tcp` me retorna un objeto de 200 elementos y al `for` le añado un contador, el ciclo continua a pesar de llegar a las 200 iteraciones, me gustaria saber si hay una forma de limpiar la memoria, o de saber porque el sniff de pyshark hace eso, y si lo estoy usando mal.

[image: Memoria usada]

En la imagen se puede ver la memoria que se come el script y cada vez es mas.
Gracias

Comment: "al for le añado un contador, el ciclo continua a pesar de llegar a las 200 iteraciones". Esto no es posible a no ser que capture.sniff retornara un iterador/generador infinito que no es el caso ¿Reinicias el contador en cada llamada a capture_tcp()? Mejor, usa enumerate para contar:  `for num, package in enumerate(capture_tcp()):` e imprime `num`...

Comment: Por otro lado, estás llamando una y otra vez a capture_tcp() debido al ciclo infinito while, deberías llamar explícitamente a `pyshark.LiveCapture.close()` cuando termine el ciclo:  `caps = capture_tcp(); for package in caps: #Procesos varios ; caps.close()`.

Comment: usando enumerate e imprimiento el contador y el tamaño del paquete siempre llega un punto que sobre pasa de iteraciones, el `while True:` lo uso para conectar a la base de datos cuando haya errores en el `for` o termine de leer los paquetes, no he intentado usar `pyshark.LiveCapture.close()` lo voy a implementar, aunque si no sale del for como tal no se ejecutara

Comment: Se me olvidaba lo más importante, para que los paquetes no se mantengan en memoria una vez obtenidos por el for necesitas indicarlo de forma explícita mediante: `capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(bpf_filter='tcp', keep_packets=False)`.  En cuanto al numero de paquetes, estará obteniendo paquetes hasta que el timeout tenga lugar, puedes limitar el timeout o limitar el número máximo de paquetes con el argumento `packet_count`. Sea como sea el número de paquetes es limitado, por tiempo o por número si usas sniff (al contrario que con sniff_continuously)

Comment: `keep_packets=False` no me funciono, me genero error, pero usar `sniff_continuously` parece que si, ya que el proceso desaparecio y no parece que se este llenando la memoria, lo dejare un rato mas ejecutandose para ver el uso de memoria y te aviso. Gracias crack